# Why does the image spill over the bottom of the div

Tags: css, html

I am working on this site: http://www.problemio.com and the blue bar image is spilling about 5px over to the bottom beyond the border of that div.

Any idea why that is happening?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your #layout div is inside your .nav_bar div.  Place the layout div after and outside of the nav_bar div and it should look more correct.

Comment: That worked.  Will accept answer when the system allows me in 8 min. I had it closed before...not sure how one of the closing tags got erased :)

Comment: @GeekedOut it happens. :)  Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Because the background iamge is on the .nav_bar.

Try putting the background image on .nav instead, also remove the width.

```
.nav_bar .nav {
  background: url('http://www.problemio.com/img/ui/problemiomainbluebar.png');
  height: 40px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 20;
}


.nav_bar {
   background-repeat: repeat-x;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #462C1F;
   border-top: 1px solid #462C1F;
   margin-top: 5px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you're putting the background image on the outer container (`.nav_bar`). It should probably be on the `.nav` element instead.

Answer (score 0):

Need something else Boss?

```
.nav_bar .nav {
  height: 50px;
}
```